# Extract text between parenthesis from a postgres table without creating additional column

Tags: regex, postgresql, substring

I am trying to extract text between parenthesis from a column in postgres table. I am using following command. It is creating an additional blank column.

```
       SELECT *, SUBSTRING (col2, '\[(.+)\]') FROM table
```

My table looks like this:

```
col1   col2
1      mut(MI_0118)
2      mut(MI_0119)
3      mut(MI_0120)

My desired output is:
col1   col2
1      MI_0118
2      MI_0119
3      MI_0120
```

How can I extract the text without creating an additional column.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is wrong, that's why you get an empty column. You don't want square brackets, but parentheses around the search string

```
select col1, substring(col2, '\((.+)\)')
from input
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cdfb0c6ad0624795fcf2c4ed915755cb)

Answer (score 0):

The `*` in the `SELECT` statement is including all columns. Then you are adding another unnamed column. If you do:

```
SELECT col1, SUBSTRING (col2, '\[(.+)\]') AS col2 FROM table
```

It will be closer to what you want.

Comment: It is only capturing the open parenthesis.

Comment: I can't test this right now, but your regex isn't quite right. It should match your string and you will have to escape the parentheses. Something like: .+\((.+)\)